# Google Verificatin file showing Page not found in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I uploaded the google verification file to the root of the server where wp-config file is.

When I am accessing the url http://www.seniorsearch.com/google4d2573ca4066c264.html, I am getting page not found error.

Any help

Comment: Hate to ask...but are you sure it's the right root folder? I only ask because I ran across: http://www.lateliving.com/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the file is not uploaded, is it showing in the list of files? are you caching the pages in wordpress?

1. Try creating a file by the same name, with same content as the google verification file.
2. You can always add a meta tag in wordpress to verify ownership

Comment: File is uploadedshttp://screencast.com/t/JSjSl3kvs
and I also added the meta tag in header file but that way it is not verifying.

Comment: the verification meta code is successfully added inside <head>. Select the "HTML tag" verification method and try again.